# error: ‘size_type’ is not a member of ‘boost::interprocess::message_queue’

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-interprocess

The program is compiling and running in my friends system correctly but when I am trying to execute on my system it is showing the above error at the following line.

```
message_queue::size_type recvd_size;

I am also included the namespace

using namespace boost::interprocess;
```

I have installed the latest boost library, using `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` but again the compiler is showing error message as 
**error: ‘size_type’ is not a member of ‘boost::interprocess::message_queue’**

Comment: Care to share the actual code that causes this error?

Comment: "c,c++" is not an entity. Boost is a C++ library. If you don't know which language you are using, how are you going to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is telling you exactly what is wrong. `boost::interprocess::message_queue` as described **[here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue_t.html)** has no `size_type` element. There are some functions there that return `size_type` so you might be interested in doing something like this:

```
int maxMessages = myMessageQueue.get_max_msg();
```

Comment: yes but it is working fine on other computer so the size_type is defined in the namespace of message_queue but i think it is the problem of linking.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to specify where boost's headers are.

```
-I /<path_boost>/include
```

If it are in:

```
/usr/local/include
```

You need this link. This because in default **PATH** of linux isn't specified.

If you open a console and digit:

```
echo $PATH
```

you'll see what path is "visible".

If you want to modify it:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

And add to PATH the string:

```
:/usr/local/include
```

**UPDATE**
Final step, logout+login or refresh /etc/environment, look [**here**](https://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting).

Comment: In my system library files are installed installed in usr/lib directory, Even though I had set PATH to the usr/lib it is no executing

Comment: have you re-defined "size_type" somewhere?

Comment: btw you have to reload /etc/environment, check update

Answer (score 1):

If you change it to `std::size_t` it will work but I think the efficient way is to follow the 
@Velthune's answer.